# I am travelling to India from the US: do I need a valid visa?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, transit-visas, domestic-travel

I am currently living in the US on a 24-month STEM OPT. I am travelling to India for visa renewal.

My itinerary is Dallas/Fort Worth-Washington/Dulles-Newark-Bombay. Do I need a valid US visa or a transit visa for this itinerary?

Comment: Oh man, that is a tough flight.   Good luck with the connection at IAD!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any kind of visa to travel around inside the USA.